# Discord only recognizing "ping" command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

In my Discord.JS bot, I have multiple commands setup (`ping`, `beep`, etc.) but Discord only recognizes "ping". I have tried multiple setups, and all are the same.

Here is my code:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName: command } = interaction;

    if (command === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    } else if (command === 'beep') {
        await interaction.reply('Boop!');
    } else if (command === 'server') {
        await interaction.reply(`Server name: ${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}`);
    } else if (command === 'user-info') {
        await interaction.reply(`Your username: ${interaction.user.username}\nYour ID: ${interaction.user.id}`);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

And here is Discords command view when "/" is enter

[image: Discords command view]

As you can see, `ping`  is the only thing being recognized by discord.

It is also worth noting the ‘ping’ command has a description which the original description I setup, so it seems like issue is that Discord is not updating the commands each time the script changes. But, I don’t know how to resolve that issue.

Comment: Does the same issue happen when using separate if statements? Looks like discord sees the if else if as one statement..

Comment: This also happens with command files so I doubt that is the issue. I will look into that anyway.

Comment: I would take a look a edit I made at the bottom of the post

Comment: Where do you register the commands? Could you add that code to your question?

Comment: Note that anything inside of the code you provided isn't responsible for what shows on discord (as a command).

Comment: Registering global commands takes up to 1 hour before it's live. If you want your command to be used immediately, you should register it on Guild-level (Development purposes). [Read more](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#registering-a-command)

Comment: I don't have a redirect URI for this bot and therefor I can't give it guild permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you **only** registered the ping command. You have to **register each** slash command individually.

I guess you registered the slashcommand some tile earlier, and have not removed it since. You are only responding in your code example to slashcommands, but you have to create them in the first hand.
Check [here](https://deploy-preview-638--discordjs-guide.netlify.app/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html) on how to do that.

> it may take up to one hour to register a global command tho, so be patient. If you are fine, with slashcommands for one guild only, you can also only create [guildCommands](https://deploy-preview-638--discordjs-guide.netlify.app/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#guild-commands). These are up and running within a view minutes (under 10minutes max)

---

Here is a simple command, with which you can update the slashcommands (this is staright from the [docs](https://deploy-preview-638--discordjs-guide.netlify.app/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#bulk-update-commands))

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '!deploy' && message.author.id === client.application?.owner.id) {
        const data = [
            {
                name: 'ping',
                description: 'Replies with Pong!',
            },
            {
                name: 'pong',
                description: 'Replies with Ping!',
            },
        ];

        const commands = await client.application?.commands.set(data);
        console.log(commands);
    }
});
```

> NOTE: you have to be running the master branch of discord.js (aka `Discord.js V13`). If you have not installed it yet, you can install it by running: `npm install discord.js@latest`. Make sure, you have uninstalled the "normal" discord.js dependency beforehand, by running `npm uninstall discord.js`.
>
> > If you are not sure what version you currently have installed, simply run `npm list`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, the idea is to render each command separately.

I also went for some hardcoded configs: guild_id & client_id (to win some time in dev mode)

```js
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token, client_id, guild_id } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});


client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

    // => client_id was just a quick fix, the correct value should be the id of the guild owner(s)
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '!deploy' && message.author.id === client_id) {
        const data = [
            {
                name: 'ping',
                description: 'Replies with Pong!',
            },
            {
                name: 'foo',
                description: 'Replies with bar!',
            },
            {
                name: 'chicken',
                description: 'Replies with sticks!',
            },
        ];

        // same here, guild_id should also be replaced by the correct call to the idea number, just as client_id in this code!
        for (let i = 0; data.length > i; i++) {
            await client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id)?.commands.create(data[i]);

        }
    }
});
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = interaction.commandName;

    if (command === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('pong')
    } else if (command === 'foo') {
        await interaction.reply('bar')
    } else if (command === 'chicken') {
        await interaction.reply('nuggets')
    }
});

client.login(token);
```