# Discord JS Commands Not Sending/Responding to Commands

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am coding a discord bot in discord.js. I am trying to implement some basic commands.

My problem: every time I try to run a command the bot does not respond. Can anybody help me?

This is my code:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    } else if (commandName === 'beep') {
        await interaction.reply('Boop!');
    } else if (commandName === 'server') {
        await interaction.reply(`Server name: ${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: 
${interaction.guild.memberCount}`);
    } else if (commandName === 'user-info') {
        await interaction.reply(`Your username: ${interaction.user.username}\nYour ID: 
${interaction.user.id}`);
    }
});


client.login('MY TOKEN');
```

Comment: have you created and registered the commands in the first place?

Comment: If you haven't registered the commands, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693070/10926046) answer from another question might be what you are missing